# How to get FB Access Token with Expo

Tags: react-native, facebook-graph-api, access-token, expo

I'm building app where i need to make Facebook Graph API requests in many places. But i dont know how to retrieve access token and then make Graph API request.

I'm using Expo, React Native and Firebase. I would like to do it without installing Xcode and/or Android Studio.

Login is working fine. My code is below:

```
async loginWithFacebook() {
try {
  const {
    type,
    token,
    expires,
    permissions,
    declinedPermissions,
  } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('<APP_ID', {
    permissions: ['email', 'public_profile'],
  });
  if (type === 'success') {
    const credential = f.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)
    f.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    var that = this;
    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=id,name&access_token=${token}`);
    const userInfo = await response.json();
    this.setState({userInfo});
    this.setState({
    dataSource: userInfo.data,
    isLoading: false,
    });
  } else {
    // type === 'cancel'
  }
} catch ({ message }) {
  alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
}
}
```

Can someone help me and give me some tips how i can use access token everywhere in my app?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Getting the `token` and saving it into `AsyncStorage`

Well the code that you have written is basically correct. You have successfully got the access token. It comes back to you when you make the `Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` request. Once you have it you could then store it in Redux or AsyncStorage to be used at a later date.

```
logIn = async () => {
  let appID = '123456789012345' // <- you'll need to add your own appID here

  try {
    const {
      type,
      token, // <- this is your access token
      expires,
      permissions,
      declinedPermissions,
    } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(appID, { permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'], });

    if (type === 'success') {
      // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
      const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=id,name&access_token=${token}`); //<- use the token you got in your request
      const userInfo = await response.json();
      alert(userInfo.name);

      // you could now save the token in AsyncStorage, Redux or leave it in state
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token); // <- save the token in AsyncStorage for later use
    } else {
      // type === 'cancel'
    }

  } catch ({ message }) {
    alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

## `app.json`

Also remember to add the following to your `app.json`, obviously replacing the values with your own. You get these by registering your app with Facebook, you can see more about that here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#registering-your-app-with-facebook

```
{ 
  "expo": {
    "facebookScheme": "fb123456789012345",
    "facebookAppId": "123456789012345",  // <- this is the same appID that you require above when making your initial request. 
    "facebookDisplayName": "you_re_facebook_app_name",
    ...
    }
}
```

## Getting `token` from `AsyncStorage`

Then if you wanted to make another request at a later time you could have a function similar to this where you get the `token` out of `AsyncStorage` and then use it to make your request.

```
makeGraphRequest = async () => {
  try {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'); // <- get the token from AsyncStorage
    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=id,name&access_token=${token}`); // <- use the token for making the graphQL request
    const userInfo = await response.json();
    alert(userInfo.name)
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.message)
  }
}
```

## Snack

I would make a snack to show you this working however, snacks do not allow editing of the `app.json` file (as far as I can tell). So here is something that you could replace your `App.js` with and then if you added your appIDs etc to the `app.json` it should work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  logIn = async () => {
    let appID = '123456789012345' // <- you'll need to add your own appID here
    try {
      const {
        type,
        token, // <- this is your access token
        expires,
        permissions,
        declinedPermissions,
      } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(appID, {
        permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],
      });
      if (type === 'success') {
        // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
        const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=id,name&access_token=${token}`); //<- use the token you got in your request
        const userInfo = await response.json();
        console.log(userInfo);
        alert(userInfo.name);
        // you could now save the token in AsyncStorage, Redux or leave it in state
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token); // <- save the token in AsyncStorage for later use
      } else {
        // type === 'cancel'
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
    }
  }

    makeGraphRequest = async () => {
      try {
        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
        const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=id,name&access_token=${token}`);
        const userInfo = await response.json();
        alert(userInfo.name)
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message)
      }
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={'Sign in to Facebook'} onPress={this.logIn} />
        <Button  title={'Make GraphQL Request'} onPress={this.makeGraphRequest} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

Comment: Great. Thank you!